# What's the equation for a line segment?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I already know that the standard equation for a line is $y=mx+b$, but what if I want the line to have specific endpoints and not go on forever? For example, the equation for a line beginning at $(3, 1)$ and ending at $(7, 2)$. Can you help me?

What's the standard equation for this?

Comment: $$\frac{x-3}{4}=\frac{y-1}{1}$$ $$x=4t+3 ,\quad y=t+1 ,\quad0\le t\le 1$$

Comment: Thats a line segment. You can write the equation of line, and then write inequalities or intervals like $x\in[3,7]$ **or** $y\in[1,2]$ to specify that it is a segment.

Comment: could you explain more? i can't understand t parameter..

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki i can't understand t parameter..

Comment: $$\frac{x-1}{4}=\frac{y-1}{1}=t\quad 0\le t\le1$$

Comment: Given two points, $p,q \in \mathbb R^n$, the **line segment** connecting $p$ and $q$ is the set of all convex combinations of $p$ and $q$

$$\{ \theta p + (1-\theta) q \mid \theta \in [0,1]\}$$

Comment: Does it matter which point we choose as the starting point of the line segment?

Answer (score 4):

You can make a parametric equation:
$$x=tx_1+(1-t)x_2$$
&
$$y=ty_1+(1-t)y_2$$
where t$\in[0,1]$. It is the internal section formula of a line, where i replaced m and n with t.

Comment: Well I imagine someone doesn't take this as a serious question, hence the $-1$ on the question also. If it's voted to close I'll delete my answer, but it's better than having another unanswered question added to the site

Comment: thanks for reply.. could you explain more? i can't understand 't' parameter..

Comment: you probably would have studied about internal section formula $x=\frac{mx_1+nx_2}{m+n}$ and $y=\frac{my_1+ny_2}{m+n}$ ,we are just dividing the line segment in m:n. So here , $t=\frac{m}{m+n}$

Comment: @Bye_World ,i will take care

Comment: Notice that $t$ can take any values between 0 and 1 (inclusive) for any values of $m$ and $n$ .For more information read this :-http://doubleroot.in/coordinate-geometry-basics-section-formula-theory/

Answer (score 2):

The equation of your line is $$y=\frac{1}{4}(x+1)$$

found from the slope formula $m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$, and solving for $y=1$ while subbing in $x=3$.

If you want a line segment rather than an infinite line you can restrict the domain of the line, restrict the allowed $x$-values:

$$y=\frac{1}{4}(x+1) \text{ for } x \in[3,7]$$

This we can see that $x=3$ we get $y=1$ and for $x=7$ we get $y=2$, and by continuity, we get all the values in between on the line, but none outside the segment we specified.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the equation of a line passing from $(3,1)$ and $(7,2)$ is $$y=\frac{1}{4}x+\frac{1}{4}$$
defined for $3<x<7$ and $1<y<2$

Now let's take $3<x<7$  and split it into two inequalities $$3<x$$ and $$x<7$$, or equivalently $$x-3>0$$ and $$7-x>0$$

Now write $$\sqrt{\frac{|7-x|}{7-x}}$$ and  $$\sqrt{\frac{|x-3|}{x-3}}$$
Notice that in $$\sqrt{\frac{|7-x|}{7-x}}$$ if I plug in a value greater than $7$ the I get a complex number, this is why I included the square root, similarly   $$\sqrt{\frac{|x-3|}{x-3}}$$ becomes complex number for values of $x$ less than $3$ (note that the purpose of the absolute values is to "normalize" the term so that the only possible values that I can get are $-1$ or $1$)

Next multiply  $$\sqrt{\frac{|7-x|}{7-x}}$$ and  $$\sqrt{\frac{|x-3|}{x-3}}$$ together and multiply with $x$ in the equation of the line to get $$y=\frac{1}{4} x \sqrt{\frac{|7-x|}{7-x}} \sqrt{\frac{|x-3|}{x-3}}+\frac{1}{4}$$
and this equation describes a line segment if you include the points $(3,1)$ and $(7,2)$

This method will work for any curve.

Comment: "and this equation describes a line segment **if** you include the points (3,1)
 and (7,2)". Meaning, the two vertices are excluded from the equation. It's worth paying extra attention.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a line segment like this:

-sqrt(x)² gives a line with a negative slope for which if x is negative, the function is undefined.

you can limit the values of y by doing: sqrt(-sqrt(x)²)² this way you cannot have any negative y values in your graph. all you have to do now is move your graph around.

for example try: -sqrt(-sqrt(x-1)²+2)²+3

Try playing around with the function to get a feel on how it works.